# How would I create and bring in a variable from another PHP page

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a table that is created in 
php. I have called this page events. I have used an include function within my user page to display the table so that a user can use the events to book an event. The thing is, I now need to create a page that will run once a user has clicked on the book now button. This page will update the booking table in my database. I am completely lost here and don't know how to go about creating this page as I think I need a variable that is brought in from the events table, perhaps via the button. The booking table in the database has these columns. Booking_ID, User_ID, Event_ID, Payment_Type and Date_Booked. I know I am using mysql but I will get the newer versions after I have this all working. I just don't know where to start on the creation of the booking PHP and inserting the values from the events table into the database. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**This is the events table that is displayed on the user page to book an event**

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if(!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("flexiflash", $con);

    // Creating the foundations for the table headings //
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>ID</th>";
        echo "<th>Venue</th>";
        echo "<th>Event</th>";
        echo "<th>Date</th>";
        echo "<th>Time</th>";
        echo "<th></th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";

    // Running a JavaScript function to check for the user's payment type before submitting the form to book_event.php //
    echo '<script>
        function check() {

        if (document.getElementById("checkbox").checked && document.getElementById("card").checked)
        {
            alert("Pay by card with 20% off");
            return true;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("checkbox").checked && document.getElementById("paypal").checked)
        {
            alert("Pay via PayPal with 20% off");
            return true;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("card").checked)
        {
            alert("Pay by card without a voucher!");
            return true;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("paypal").checked)
        {
            alert("Pay via PayPal without a voucher!");
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            alert("Nothing was checked. Please select your payment type");
            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>';

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    // Outputting the data from the $result variable into a formatted table //
    echo "<tbody>";
    echo "<form class='table-form'  action='book_event.php' method='post' onsubmit='return check()'>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Event_ID'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Event_Venue'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Event_Name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Event_Date'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Event_Time'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='submit' class='sub_btn'  value='Book now'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</tbody>";
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

If you need any more code or any other information please feel free to ask.

I know my code is not great and I am using Javascript inside my PHP but I am still learning PHP. Only been doing this for about 2 months, so I know its not the best.

Comment: use `$_SESSION` super global variable

Comment: Btw don't use so many echo statements. You can either close the php tag (?>) and write normal html, then open it again when you need to. Otherwise one echo statement with line-breaks in it will work perfectly.

Comment: I am using sessions, just not in this page as I am only including it on another page.

Answer (score 0):

If the page you are sending your data to is on the same host then SESSION might be what youre looking for. You can also use the form to POST data, via a form action to another page to process the data. If the data isnt sensitive then you can pass vars between pages with GET or even cookies, but it seems that passing the data isn't your main concern here.

One option to look at is creating a separate page to handle the form processing and insert the data, this can be called in [the form action tag](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

It sounds like you are new to this and it might over complicate things but it is worth looking at [MVC to separate concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will certainly have a look.

Comment: what I think I need is the Event_ID here echo "<td>" . $row['Event_ID'] . "</td>"; so that I can use this on the booking page to insert the data from the table into my database.